# DB2 10.5 - When inserting, the database is trying to reuse index keys on GENERATE ALWAYS

Tags: index, db2, primary-key

I am trying to insert a row into a database table which has a `GENERATED ALWAYS` primary key column. The table has over 1000 rows, and the primary keys start at 1. When I try to do an insert, the error message indicates that DB2 is autogenerating the id 1 and trying to insert, which causes an error since that primary key already exists.

This is the error message:

> One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or
>   foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because
>   the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "1"
>   constrains table "PROJECTMGMT.TIMESHEET" from having duplicate
>   values for the index key.

This is my primary key:

```
"TIMESHEET_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( 
   START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE -2147483648 MAXVALUE 2147483647 
   NO CYCLE CACHE 20 NO ORDER 
),
```

To try to troubleshoot the issue, I changed the `TIMESHEET_ID` column to `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` so that I could manually enter a primary key value and the query worked.

I am fairly new to DB2, and this has me stumped. I haven't been able to find any fix for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Determine the largest current ID value:

```
select max(TIMESHEET_ID) from PROJECTMGMT.TIMESHEET
```

then reset the identity value:

```
alter table PROJECTMGMT.TIMESHEET 
  alter column TIMESHEET_ID restart with <whatever the max value is + 1>
```

Answer (score 0):

`GENERATE BY DEFAULT` means that you can provide a value or you can allow DB2 to provide a value. If you use `GENERATE BY DEFAULT` and you provide a value, you may need to `ALTER TABLE` to reset the identity as DB2 will retain the last value it was at (rather than what you inserted into the table).

`GENERATE ALWAYS` means just that. Only DB2 can create values for this field. You cannot `INSERT` a value into this field. Just remove the identity value from your `INSERT` statements and you will be fine. Now if you use `IMPORT` or `db2move` to move the data (I'm thinking `LOAD` too, but not positive on that), this is a constraint, so you may need to drop the constraint first, bring in the data, and then add the constraint back and `ALTER TABLE` to reset where the identity starts with.

Comment: As mentioned, the table was originally `GENERATE ALWAYS`, and there was no value specified for the primary key field. I just changed it and added the primary key to make sure that was in fact the issue.